# Unique Constraint on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Supplier` with columns such as `ID`, `Name`, `Address`, `PhoneNo` and `Shop` etc.

I want to add a unique constraint on `Name` column depending upon shop.

For example if SHOP A has two Suppliers A and B and SHOP B has also two Suppliers C and B. if I add Supplier A again in shop A it will not allow it because A is already there, but if i want to add Supplier C in Shop A it will allow me to add because Supplier C is only unique in SHOP B.

Any ideas how I will accomplished it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a unique index on `name` and `stop`:

```
create unique index idx_supplier_shop_name on supplier(shop, name)
```

This should do exactly what you want.

As a note:  you can equivalently do this with a unique constraint in the table definition or via `alter table` as well.